# Mysql invalid datetime format, but only in specific time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert a record to MySQL, but it fails with the following message:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-25 02:54:00' for column 'trial_ends_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `subscriptions` (`name`, `stripe_id`, `stripe_plan`, `quantity`, `trial_ends_at`, `ends_at`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (default, redacted_id, redacted_id, 1, 2018-03-25 02:54:00, , 762, 2018-03-18 01:54:08, 2018-03-18 01:54:08))
```

The following update also fails:

```
UPDATE `subscriptions`
    SET `trial_ends_at` = '2018-03-25 02:00:00'
    WHERE `id` = '636'
```

> 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-25 02:00:00' for column 'trial_ends_at' at row 1

But only on my local machine (works fine on remote server) and only with dates in the 2018-03-25 02:xx:xx range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to speculate, you are in Europe, where daylight saving time ends on 2018-03-25 at 2:00 a.m. in the  morning.  That means that one second after "2018-03-25 01:59:59" is "2018-03-25 03:00:00".

In other words, the time is invalid, which is why you are getting an error.

I would suggest that you use "2018-03-25 03:00:00" for local time or use UTC -- which doesn't have daylight saving time issues.

Comment: That is it, I would never guessed it, our server uses UTC so its not a problem, thanks